# How should I separate functions, class definitions and main code within a project?

Tags: c++

I currently have a project with 3 files.

One `DBheader.h` header file that includes:

- Class declarations (with their smaller member function definitions)

A `DBdefinitions.cpp` file with:

- Larger member function definitions for the classes in `DBheader.h`

and finally a `DBmain.cpp` file that contains:

- Main code
- Some large (non-memeber) functions that use the classes defined in `DBheader.h`

I would preferably like to move these functions somewhere to make my `DBmain.cpp` file less cluttered. Should/could I move them to the `DBdefinition.cpp` file or do I need to create a new separate `.cpp` file for non-member functions?

Here's a rough of what my code looks like if the above is unclear.

```
//DBheader.h

//libraries..

class course{
//member data..

void printinfo();

}
```

-

```
//DBdefinitions.cpp

#include "DBheader.h"
void course::printinfo(){/*do stuff*/}
```

-

```
//DBmain.cpp

#include "DBheader.h"
typedef map<int,course> record;
void fileinput(record &map);
int main(){
//stuff
}
void fileinput(record &map){
//lots of code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should organize free functions that are part of the public interface in a similar fashion you used for the `class` definition: a header with the declaration and an implementation file with the implementations.

If they are particular to a specific translation unit, keep them in that implementation file.

All free functions should be declared inside a `namespace` (named for the public ones, anonymous for "private" free functions).